# indexes that appear to be redundant with clustered PK

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a database at a client with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Example] (
  [ID]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  ....
  [AddressID]  INT NULL,
  [RepName]    VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  ....
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Example] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

And it has the following indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Example_Address]
  ON [example]( [ID] ASC, [AddressId] ASC);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Example_Rep]
  ON [example]( [ID] ASC, [RepName] ASC);
```

To me these are appear to be redundant with the clustered Index. I cannot imagine any scenario where these would be beneficial. If anyone can come up with a situation where these would be useful, let me know.

Here is another example:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Example_IsDeleted]
  ON [example]( [IsDeleted] ASC)
  INCLUDE( [ID], [SomeNumber]);
```

Why would you need to INCLUDE [ID]? My understanding is that the clustered index key is already present in every non-clustered index, so why would they do that? I would just INCLUDE ([SomeNumber])

Comment: I think I found my answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747308/is-it-bad-to-have-a-non-clustered-index-that-contains-the-primary-key-from-the-c

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that the clustered index key is already included in every non-clustered index, but not in the same sense as your example clustered indices suggest.

For example, if you have a non-clustered index as in your example for IDX_Example_Rep, and you run this query:

`SELECT [RepName], [Id] FROM [Example] WHERE [RepName] = 'some_value';`

The IDX_Example_Rep index will be used, but it will be an index scan (every row will be checked). This is because the [Id] column was specified as the first column in the index.

If the index is instead specified as follows:

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Example_Rep]
  ON [example]([RepName] ASC);`

Then when you run the same sample query, the IDX_Example_Rep index is used and the operation is an index seek - the engine knows *exactly* where to find the records by [RepName] within the IDX_Example_Rep index and, because the only other field being returned by the SELECT is the [Id] field, which is the key of the clustered index and therefore included in the non-clustered index, no further operations are necessary.

If the SELECT list were expanded to include, say, the [AddressId] field, then you'll find the engine still performs the index seek against IDX_Example_Rep to find the correct records, but then also has do a key lookup against the clustered index to get the "other" fields (the [AddressId] in this example).

So, no - you probably don't want to repeat the [Id] column as part of the non-clustered indices in general, but when it comes to non-clustered indices you definitely want to pay attention to your SELECTed fields and know whether or not you're covering the fields you're going to need.